# Audio recording app on iPhone, that can sync large audio files to PC

Tags: iphone, recording

The default voice recorder on iPhone OS 3.0 doesn't allow you to send large files via email, or sync it to PC. Are there any other free or $0.99 apps that do this nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Griffin iTalk](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/italk) is a free application that does this very well. You can sync wirelessly to a pc using their iTalk application.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [QuickVoice](http://www.nfinityinc.com/quickvoiceip.html) for iPhone recordings and found it easy to use. I haven't tried transferring large files, but they provide [QuickVoice Sync](http://quickvoice-sync.software.informer.com/) which can transfer large files.

Another option is [Griffin iTalk](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/italk) though I haven't tried it myself.

Here are [reviews of both applications](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2008/08/two-voice-recording-apps-for-the-iphone/) though a year old.